# script to compare text in different files

Tags: linux, bash, ip, compare

i've a less knowledge about linux.
i 've a file "iplast.txt" and i need that when the text into this file is not equal to the result of this command http://ipinfo.io/ip the script send me a mail.

i've tried like this

```
     if

            [ 'cat iplast.txt' = 'curl http://ipinfo.io/ip' ]

     then

            echo 'ip same'

     else

            #send mail command that i already know
```

fi

but the cat command compare not the file iplast.txt but the word "iplast.txt" whit the curl command.

last thing, it need to work with FFP(Funz Fun Plug)

i tried three day but as i already said i know linux just a little. so pls help me tnk!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
curl http://ipinfo.io/ip > ipnow.txt
OUTPUT="$(diff iplast.txt ipnow.txt)"
if [ "$OUTPUT" = ""]; then
    echo "ip same"
else
    echo "ip different"
fi
```

I also suggest using python rather than bash scripting if possible. This bash stuff is quite cryptic.

Comment: TNK you for the answer, this is the result

Comment: ./ipchange: line 5: [: 1c1
< xx.xx.xx.xx.xx
---
> xx.xx.xx.xx.xx: unary operator expected
ip different
i don't know python, but ill try i promise.